# how to change html5 tableView section color?

Tags: html5-appcache

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li data-role="list-divider">A</li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a></li>
  <li data-role="list-divider">B</li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Bob Cabot</a></li>

 </ul>
```

[image]

how can i change the scetion color? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're asking a simple change of color. But if I'm right :

You should simply add a class. 
Then go to the css and there just add a `.classname{ background-color: #color;}`

Is that you are asking for ?

Comment: yes, sorry i'm a beginer, thank you help me. the answer like this?                                      <li data-role="list-divider", class = "section">Site</li>
            li.section{ background-color: #FFF;}

Comment: Yes it is ! Or if you prefer, just will work with .sectio -->

.section{ background-color: #FFF;}

Comment: please mark my answer for the correct one please! I'll will give me some reputation :D  @BestWater